# Php access variable

Tags: php

In PHP i have array variable from another function like this
$v->params:

```
(
    [{"username":"myusername","email":"myemail@gmail_com","phone":"0123456789","password":"abc123","fullname":"myfullname","register_ip":"127_0_0_1","country":"Qu\u1ed1c_Gia","birthday":"N\u0103m_sinh","gender":"male","bank_code":"Ng\u00e2n_h\u00e0ng","ip":"127_0_0_1","os":"Windows_10","device":"Computer","browser":"Mozilla_Firefox_77_0"}] => 
)
```

Now i want to access to it item, how can i code to access item value like this:

```
$password = $v->params->password; //myemail@gmail_com
```

I new with PHP thank you all

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it. (Here's a good [Markdown Tutorial](https://commonmark.org/help/) as well).

Comment: you are doing encode and decode at same time $object = json_decode (json_encode($v->params), TRUE);

can you explain it once

Comment: thank you, i want to access item of it array but dont known how, json_decode (json_encode($v->params), TRUE i follow on stackoverflow but still not luck

Comment: @ForgeWebDesign This is a pretty common practice to convert an array that contains JSON strings to an actual array.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton nice with your comment, i want to access to it item in array as you explan: $v->params->username //myusername but dont known how to write code

Comment: i can see that my array not normal with end at "=> )" that why i can not parse it

Comment: @ForgeWebDesign i have update question again

Comment: As it is difficult to see what the variable contains, can you add `var_export($v);` please.

Comment: @NigelRen, thank you, result that i get:
 api::__set_state(array(
   'method' => 'POST',
   'endpoint' => 'userms',
   'version' => 'v1',
   'function' => 'register',
   'params' => 
  array (
    '{"username":"myusernamehere","email":"myemail@gmail_com","phone":"0123456789","password":"abc123","fullname":"myfullname","register_ip":"127_0_0_1","country":"Qu\\u1ed1c_Gia","birthday":"N\\u0103m_sinh","gender":"male","bank_code":"Ng\\u00e2n_h\\u00e0ng","ip":"127_0_0_1","os":"Windows_10","device":"Computer","browser":"Mozilla_Firefox_77_0"}' => '',
  ),
   'file' => NULL,
))

Comment: the readability of this question is not good at all. but it seems that your return value from that function is a JSON data. it would be easier to render that value into an array via **json_decode**. from then, i believe you will be quite fine getting your way around values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data seems the wrong way round as it's the key of the array rather than a value.

So using `array_keys()[0]` to get the first key and then `json_decode` this...

```
$data = json_decode(array_keys($v->params)[0]);
```

you can then use the `$data` object to get at the values...

```
echo $data->username;
```

Comment: it return me with this:

[16-Jun-2020 20:16:18 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type api as array in C:\userms\restful_api.php:147
Stack trace:
#0 C:\userms\restful_api.php(129): restful_api::userms_register(Object(api))
#1 C:\userms\restful_api.php(105): restful_api->userms(Object(api))
#2 C:\userms\restful_api.php(42): restful_api->_process_api()
#3 C:\userms\api.php(7): restful_api->__construct()
#4 C:\userms\api.php(30): api->__construct()
#5 {main}
  thrown in C:\userms\restful_api.php on line 147

Comment: Try it with `$v->params` instead.